# Swiftui NavigationView + TabView doesn't show navbar item

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

I have four Views inside a `TabView` and each of them contains `NavigationView` with title. However, when the view first shows up, the navigation view does not show as designed.

Even though I have the navigation bar item, the view would always be a blank child view. It is only when I click to another page and then coming back to the navigation view that the view would show normally. What could be the problems?

Attached is the screenshot of the preview page. Thanks in advance.

```
struct MainContentView: View {
    @State private var navSelection = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .center){
          
            TabView(selection:$navSelection){
                NavigationView{
                    HomeView()
                        .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Title").font(.system(size:24,weight: .heavy)), trailing: Image(systemName: "bell.fill"))
                        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
                       
                }.tag(0)
                
                NavigationView{
                    ExploreView()
                       
                }.tag(1)
        
                Text("Post").tag(2)
                Text("Market").tag(3)
                Text("Account").tag(4)
            }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .disabled(true)
            
            MainTabBarView(navSelection: self.$navSelection)
            }
    }
}
```

[image]

[The preview sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUoXS.png)

Comment: Interesting bug... it looks like PageTabViewStyle tab view uses internally navigation stack as well which conflicts with your child navigation view stack.

Comment: Wow... then does it mean I do not have to specify the navigation view at this stage and use the navigation link directly inside the home view?

Comment: @ccnn or just get rid of the tab view and make your own custom one. Might be more customizable

Comment: had to just give up the tabview, thx!

Answer (score 2):

Just a small mistake, apply the style to the navigation view as follows:

```
NavigationView{ 
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

What went wrong is some how SwiftUI found a detail view somewhere in the hierarchy and pushed it because normally inside NavigationView there are two views defined but you only defined one. I think `.tabViewStyle` is what caused it.

Also to set the nav item title we use `.navigationTitle("Home")`