# NavigationView inside TabView not displaying correctly in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swiftui

Navigation View inside Tabview
No issue in portrait mode
In landscape mode, navigation view and all subviews are "collapsed" into a top-level menu.
See screen shots below.

Is it normal behaviour?
Could not find any modifier to change this behaviour if it is normal.

[Portrait mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQrAq.jpg)

[Landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mTat.jpg)

[Landscape mode after clicking top left menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4O4q.jpg)

Test project showing issue:-

```
TabView {
    ChartView().tabItem {
        Label("Chart", systemImage: "chart.bar")
    }
    Page1View().tabItem {
        Label("Received", systemImage: "tray.and.arrow.down.fill")
    }
}

body of Page1View struct:-
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
        // ... removed for clarity
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Text("tbar1")
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Text("tbar2")
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Text("tbar3")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swiftui NavigationView + TabView doesn't show navbar item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70912438/swiftui-navigationview-tabview-doesnt-show-navbar-item)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to this issue is that same as listed in:-
[Swiftui NavigationView + TabView doesn't show navbar item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70912438/swiftui-navigationview-tabview-doesnt-show-navbar-item)

Added navigationViewStyle of .stack:-

```
NavigationView{ 
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```